# How to manage UX auth error with react-native?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, authentication

I setup a basic auth system following the [react-navigation auth flow guide](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/) with [FeathersJS react-native client](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/client.html#react-native).

Here is my main `index.tsx` file:

```js
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, {
  useReducer, useEffect, useMemo, ReactElement,
} from 'react';
import { Platform, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import { useFonts } from '@use-expo/font';
import SplashScreen from './screens/SplashScreen';
import { AuthContext } from './contexts';
import { client } from './utils';
import DrawerNavigator from './navigation/DrawerNavigator';
import LogonStackNavigator from './navigation/LogonStackNavigator';

interface State {
  isLoading: boolean;
  isSignOut: boolean;
  userToken: string|null;
}

const App = (): ReactElement => {
  /* eslint-disable global-require */
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'Lato-Regular': require('../assets/fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf'),
    'Lato-Bold': require('../assets/fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf'),
    'Poppins-Light': require('../assets/fonts/Poppins-Light.ttf'),
    'Poppins-Bold': require('../assets/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf'),
  });
  /* eslint-enable global-require */

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
    (prevState: State, action): State => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'RESTORE_TOKEN':
          return {
            ...prevState,
            userToken: action.token,
            isLoading: false,
          };
        case 'SIGN_IN':
          return {
            ...prevState,
            isSignOut: false,
            userToken: action.token,
          };
        case 'SIGN_OUT':
          return {
            ...prevState,
            isSignOut: true,
            userToken: null,
          };
        default:
          return prevState;
      }
    },
    {
      isLoading: true,
      isSignOut: false,
      userToken: null,
    },
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const bootstrapAsync = async (): Promise<void> => {
      let userToken;

      try {
        const auth = await client.reAuthenticate();
        console.log('reAuthenticate:', auth);
        userToken = auth.accessToken;
      } catch (e) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('reAuthenticate failure:', e);
      }

      dispatch({
        type: 'RESTORE_TOKEN',
        token: userToken,
      });
    };

    bootstrapAsync();
  }, []);

  const authContext = useMemo(
    () => ({
      signIn: async (data) => {
        // In a production app, we need to send some data (usually username, password) to server and get a token
        // We will also need to handle errors if sign in failed
        // After getting token, we need to persist the token using `AsyncStorage`
        // In the example, we'll use a dummy token
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('signIn', data);

        try {
          const auth = await client.authenticate({
            strategy: 'local',
            ...data,
          });
          console.log(auth);
          dispatch({
            type: 'SIGN_IN',
            token: 'dummy-auth-token',
          });
        } catch (e) {
          console.log('signIn failure:', e);
        }
      },
      signOut: async () => {
        try {
          await client.logout();
          dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_OUT' });
        } catch (e) {
          console.log('signOut failure:', e);
        }
      },
      signUp: async (data) => {
        // In a production app, we need to send user data to server and get a token
        // We will also need to handle errors if sign up failed
        // After getting token, we need to persist the token using `AsyncStorage`
        // In the example, we'll use a dummy token
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('signUp', data);

        dispatch({
          type: 'SIGN_IN',
          token: 'dummy-auth-token',
        });
      },
    }),
    [],
  );

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  }

  if (state.isLoading) {
    return <SplashScreen />;
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
      {Platform.OS === 'ios' && (
        <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      )}
      {state.userToken == null ? (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <LogonStackNavigator />
        </NavigationContainer>
      ) : (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <DrawerNavigator />
        </NavigationContainer>
      )}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And my `SiginScreen.tsx` file which handle the login form:

```js
import React, { ReactElement } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { RouteProp } from '@react-navigation/core';
import { AuthContext } from '../contexts';
import {
  LogonHeader, Button, Input, Text, TextLink,
} from '../components';
import { LogonStackParamList } from '../navigation/LogonStackNavigator';

interface Props {
  navigation: StackNavigationProp<LogonStackParamList, 'SignIn'>;
  route: RouteProp<LogonStackParamList, 'SignIn'>;
}

const SignInScreen = ({ navigation }: Props): ReactElement => {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');

  const { signIn } = React.useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      style={styles.container}
      behavior="padding"
    >
      <LogonHeader title="Se connecter" />
      <Input
        placeholder="E-mail"
        value={email}
        onChangeText={setEmail}
        keyboardType="email-address"
      />
      <Input
        placeholder="Mot de passe"
        value={password}
        onChangeText={setPassword}
        secureTextEntry
      />
      <Button
        title="Connexion"
        onPress={() => signIn({
          email,
          password,
        })}
      />
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};

export default SignInScreen;
```

It works as expected, but I can't figure out how to handle the error case.

Currently, it's just a `console.log` statement on `index.tsx` file.

How can I properly informs the `SignInScreen` component that the logins fail to show a message at the user end? Should I use redux or something?

More exactly: I would like to put an error text message directly on `SignInScreen` in case of failure.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you could add a new property to your `global state` which could be possibly `null` that indicates the given Auth error, then you can dispatch everytime the service returns an error. If you are willing to change your approach, I'd suggest that you only store in a global state the user token, you can manage the `isLoading` individually in each screen and the `isSignOut` could be derived from the token. You will reduce the the number of re renders and will simplify the logic behind it.

EDIT:
This is a code sample of what you can do:

```
// main index.tsx
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, {
  useReducer, useEffect, useMemo, ReactElement,
} from 'react';
import { Platform, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import { useFonts } from '@use-expo/font';
import SplashScreen from './screens/SplashScreen';
import { AuthContext } from './contexts';
import { client } from './utils';
import DrawerNavigator from './navigation/DrawerNavigator';
import LogonStackNavigator from './navigation/LogonStackNavigator';

interface State {
  isLoading: boolean;
  isSignOut: boolean;
  userToken: string|null;
  //we add a new property to your state object to make visible the errors
  authError: string|null;
}

const App = (): ReactElement => {
  // keep the same code, deleted for simplicity

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
    (prevState: State, action): State => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'RESTORE_TOKEN':
          return {
            ...prevState,
            authError: null,
            userToken: action.token,
            isLoading: false,
          };
        case 'SIGN_IN':
          return {
            ...prevState,
            isSignOut: false,
            authError: null,
            userToken: action.token,
          };
        case 'SIGN_OUT':
          return {
            ...prevState,
            isSignOut: true,
            authError: null,
            userToken: null,
          };
        case: 'AUTH_ERROR':
          return {
            ...prevState,
            authError: action.error
          };
        default:
          return prevState;
      }
    },
    {
      isLoading: true,
      isSignOut: false,
      userToken: null,
      authError: null,
    },
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const bootstrapAsync = async (): Promise<void> => {

      try {
        const auth = await client.reAuthenticate();
        console.log('reAuthenticate:', auth);
        dispatch({
          type: 'RESTORE_TOKEN',
          token: auth.accessToken,
        });
      } catch (e) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('reAuthenticate failure:', e);
        dispatch({
          type: 'AUTH_ERROR',
          token: e, //or what ever your want to show
        });
      }
    };

    bootstrapAsync();
  }, []);

  const authContext = useMemo(
    () => ({
    //we add state here in order to access it from 
    //React.useContext(AuthContext);
       state,
    //put your code here
    }),
    [],
  );

/*
...YOUR CODE...
*/
```

Basically, in the code above we added a new property `authError` to your global state. Then, you need a new action to update that property. Then, in your authContext we add the global state to be retrieved from anywhere.
To keep simplicity, I just added one dispatch with `AUTH_ERROR` action in your code, but you can do the same in `signIn`, `signUp` and `signOut`.

in your `SiginScreen.tsx` you can do the following:

```
const SignInScreen = ({ navigation }: Props): ReactElement => {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');

  //we get the state we added in our AuthContext
  const { signIn, state } = React.useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      style={styles.container}
      behavior="padding"
    >
      <LogonHeader title="Se connecter" />
      <Input
        placeholder="E-mail"
        value={email}
        onChangeText={setEmail}
        keyboardType="email-address"
      />
      <Input
        placeholder="Mot de passe"
        value={password}
        onChangeText={setPassword}
        secureTextEntry
      />
      <Button
        title="Connexion"
        onPress={() => signIn({
          email,
          password,
        })}
      />
    {/* shows the error if any, otherwise it won't be shown */}
    {state.authError && <Text>{state.authError}</Text>}
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};
```

Comment: I am not sure to follow you. Plus, `isLoading` is only use for the SplashScreen. Here I want to add some text on SigninScreen in case of failure. May you add some code sample?

Comment: Much better thanks! At the meanwhile, I found another way: I catch the exception throw from the signIn method on my signInScreen. But I don't know if it's a better practise than your solution...

Comment: @Soullivaneuh I'd say yes. I personally manage this auth flow at screen level. Doing so you will avoid some rerenders that could affect the performance for your app unless you need to know the error from another screen. That's what I meant in my suggestion, I thought you couldn't do it by the way you structured your project

Comment: Not sure to well understand your last comment. So the state approach you gave to me is better than my solution according to best practices?

Comment: @Soullivaneuh no sir, look at your question. Yours is a better practice :)